# save image from fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using fileupload control to have image on the form and that that image has to be saved on some folder in hard disk say `"E:\\asp_net"`.

Is there any possible way to save image on disk from fileupload and if there is any other image with same name, it should be overwritten?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need to save the file in your `machine's E drive`?

Your ultimate option should be in your Application Folder. It should be like...

```
 FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/AppFolderName/" + FileName));
```

Comment: i am using server.mappath, but by this it is looking in current project folder, but there is no image in the project..

Comment: fileuplImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(" ~/image_path/" + fileuplImage.FileName));

Comment: it is looking the folder in the current project folder. but my destination folder is not in current project. it is located somewhere else..

Comment: then it should be fileuplImage.SaveAs(@"E:\\asp_net\\" + fileuplImage.FileName));

Comment: as Server.mappath will look into current project. you have to provide complete path as What I have mention in above comment.

Comment: by using this it is giving an error "The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path,"

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the cunningly-named `SaveAs` method.

Comment: yes i do use saveas, but it is giving an error "rooted path not found"

Comment: i think you have to do Server.MapPath + yourFolder

Comment: var file = Path.Combine(@image_path, fileuplImage.FileName);
            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                File.Delete(file);
            }
            fileuplImage.SaveAs(file);
           where image_path is configured with "E:\aspnet_app\source\resources\images\"

Comment: The error is telling you that ASP.Net is configured to require a path that starts with `~/`.  (Application-relative)

Answer (score 1):

following videos cover for your needs;

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-simple-file-uploads-in-aspnet

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-multiple-file-uploads-in-aspnet-1

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-multiple-file-uploads-in-aspnet-2

Answer (score 0):

```
var filename = Path.Combine(@"E:\asp_net", myFileUploadControl.FileName);
if (File.Exists(filename))
   File.Delete(filename);
myFileUploadControl.SaveAs(filename);
```

Comment: i am using the same code, but it is giving an error. that "it is not a rooted path, please give rooted path"

Comment: it is saying "saveas: method is configured to require a rooted path

Comment: The path needs to be an absolute path, not a relative one. I.e. it needs to start with a drive letter and be followed by the complete path.